# How to parse JSON containing object and JSON Array without key?

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

I have a JSON response which I have to show on activity. The problem I'm having 
 is with the JSON Array that is present in the response. I want to parse it and show the data on the activity, in response the "start_times" array I want to show only one data at a time...

This is the JSON response i'm getting from the server

```
{
    "data": {
        "start_times": [
            [
                "08:00:00",
                "09:00:00"
            ],
            [
                "09:00:00",
                "10:00:00"
            ],
            [
                "10:00:00",
                "11:00:00"
            ]
        ],
        "mon": [
            {
                "subject__name": Electronics,
                "faculty__first_name": Manoj
            },
            {
                "subject__name": null,
                "faculty__first_name": null
            },
            {
                "subject__name": null,
                "faculty__first_name": null
            }
        ]
         }
}
```

My code:

```
  final StringRequest myStringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>()
  {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response)
    {
      Log.i(TAG, "Response-->" + response);
      System.out.println(response);
      try
      {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONObject obj2 = obj.getJSONObject("data");
        JSONArray timetable = obj2.getJSONArray("mon");

        JSONArray timeTableTime = obj2.getJSONArray("start_times");
        Log.d(TAG, "timeTableTime-->" + timeTableTime);

        Log.d(TAG, "TimetableLength-->" + timetable.length());
        for (int i = 0; i < timetable.length(); i++)
        {
          JSONObject heroObject = timetable.getJSONObject(i);

          mondayHero mon = new mondayHero(
              heroObject.getString("faculty__first_name"),
              heroObject.getString("subject__name"),
              heroObject.getString("faculty__first_name"),
              obj2.getJSONArray("start_times"));
          Log.d(TAG, "mon-->" + mon);
          mondayList.add(mon);

        }

        //creating custom adapter object
        mondayListViewAdaptor adapter = new mondayListViewAdaptor(mondayList, c.getApplicationContext());

        //adding the adapter to listview
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

      }

    }
  }
```

Actual result is =

```
Subject : Electronics
Faculty : Manoj
Time : [["08:00:00","09:00:00"],
       ["09:00:00","10:00:00"],
       ["10:00:00","11:00:00"]]

Subject : null
Faculty : null
Time : [["08:00:00","09:00:00"],
       ["09:00:00","10:00:00"],
       ["10:00:00","11:00:00"]]

Subject : null
Faculty : null
Time : [["08:00:00","09:00:00"],
       ["09:00:00","10:00:00"],
       ["10:00:00","11:00:00"]]
```

Expected Result(i want) is =

```
Subject : Electronics
Faculty : Manoj
Time : 08:00:00-09:00:00

Subject : null
Faculty : null
Time : 09:00:00-10:00:00

Subject : null
Faculty : null
Time : 10:00:00-11:00:00
```

Any Idea how to solve this problem??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the corrected code. Use the `timeTableTime` array in your for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < timetable.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject heroObject = timetable.getJSONObject(i);
    JSONObject timeObject = timetableTime.getJSONObject(i);

    mondayHero mon = new mondayHero(
        heroObject.getString("faculty__first_name"),
        heroObject.getString("subject__name"),
        heroObject.getString("faculty__first_name"),
        timeObject);
    Log.d(TAG,"mon-->"+mon);
    mondayList.add(mon);
}
```

Comment: This is working for me, thanks i got the idea now. But my output is showing as
Time : ["08:00:00","09:00:00"] after using 
String time = hero.getTime().toString(); any idea @Deepak Khillare

Comment: Yes, you'll need to split the string array and join them using `-` separator. So instead of doing `timetableTime.getJSONObject(i)` you can do `timeTableTime.getJSONArray(i)` which will return you the array. And then you can use `timeObject[0] - timeObject[1]` for getting the desired result.

Comment: `timeTableTime.getJSONArray(i).join("-");`